# Javascript: Find numbers of keywords in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Input:**

```
var text = $('#id_textarea').val();
var keywords = $('#id_keywords').val().split(',');
```

**Output:** Number of `keywords` in `text`

**Example:**

```
text = "jquery javascript js jquery-js js django python, blah blah blah...";
keywords = ['jquery', 'js'];
// so result = 3
```

Thanks for any help :)

UPDATE: I need a function to get the result as output. Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a request for us to make this for him, than a question, it would seem. Have you looked through jQuery's list of functions to see if there is a suitable one?

Comment: This question is not really jQuery specific, rather a general question on how to get number of matches of particular keywords in a string. jQuery is of no help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, the logic should work though.

```
var textParts = text.split(' ');
var count = 0;

for (var index = 0; index < keywords.length; index++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
        if (textParts[i].match(keywords[index])) {
            count++; // found match, increment count
        }
    }
}

alert(count); // alert the amount of matches found
```

**Edit**

I tested this and the result is 5.

You will have to test if it *equals* then instead of using `match()`.

```
if (textParts[i] == keywords[index]) { // works
```

[See it in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mmmshuddup/9637g/1/)